# How to check if fadeOut() is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if a fadeOut is done?

I tried this, but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
$('.alert-success').show().fadeOut(), {
  duration: 9000,
  complete: function () {
    alert("test");
  }
};
```

Comment: alert is missing ending parenthesis.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). The whole piece of code is a mess (sorry).

Comment: Yea, when i copied the code, i didnt copy the ending parenthesis, my bad. Thank you

Comment: @Glund mark some of the answers as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) you can create a callback as the second argument and it will fire when completed.

E.g.

```
$('.alert-success').show().fadeOut(9000, function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There are syntax errors with your `alert()` call and you specify the duration and callback as parameters:

```
$('.alert-success').show().fadeOut(9000,function () {
        alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Yea, when i copied the code, i didnt copy the ending parenthesis, my bad. Thank you